# Deducing the probability measure from the distibution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $X_t$ be an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued stochastic process on the probability space $( \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Given $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, I am interested in finding a probability measure $P^{x}$ 
on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F} )$ such that
$$
P^x ( X_t \in B ) = P ( X_t + x \in B), \quad B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^d}).
$$

1. Does there there exist a probability measure $P^x$ satisfying the above-mentioned relation?
2. If such a measure exists, is it unique? If it is not unique, what additional assumptions are needed to make it unique?

We can consider the distribution of $X_t +x$ on $( \mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^d}))$ given by the convolution $P_{ X_t } * \delta_x$, but what can we say about a corresponding probability measure on $( \Omega, \mathcal{F})$? Could Kolmogorov extension theorem be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such a measure exists, but it is not unique.

**Existence.** Consider the mapping $f\colon \Omega\to\Omega$ that sends the sample path $(\omega_t)$ to $(\omega_t-x)$. This mapping is measurable, so one can form the pushforward measure $f_{\star}P$, and verify (by definition of the pushforward) that $f_{\star}P(X_t\in B)=P(X_t+x\in B)$. Thus, we may set $P^x=f_{\star}P$.

**Non-Uniqueness.** For example, consider a Brownian motion $(B_t\colon t\in[0,1])$ and let $(X_t\colon t\in[0,1])$ be a [fractional Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion) with Hurst parameter $H=\tfrac14$, so that for all $t\in[0,1]$, we have that $X_t$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sqrt{t}$. (Its covariance is equal to
$$
\mathbb EX_tX_s=\frac{\sqrt{t}+\sqrt{s}-\sqrt{t-s}}{2},
$$
although that is not very important to this answer.)
Then, the process $(B'_t\colon t\in[0,1])$ given by $B'_t=t^{1/4}X_t$ has the property that $B'_t$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $t$, just like $B_t$, whereas the processes $(B'_t\colon t\in[0,1])$ and $(B_t\colon t\in [0,1])$ have different distributions since the former has negatively correlated increments yet the latter has independent increments. This shows that even in the case $x=0$ of your question, the measure is not unique.

Comment: You write that $f$ is a mapping from $\Omega$ to $\Omega$. What are $\omega_t$ and $\omega_t - x$ exactly and why are they elements of $\Omega$?

Comment: You neglected to mention what the indexing interval of your process was, so to keep things simple I chose a notation that also suppresses the indexing interval - but I see this has confused you. So let's assume your stochastic process is indexed by a time interval $T$, so that the sample path is described by a function $g\colon T\to \mathbb R$ given by $g(t)=X_t$. The canonical sample space for such a process is the space of functions from $T$ to $\mathbb R$. Thus each $\omega\in\Omega$ can be written as $\omega=(\omega_t\colon t\in T)$. When I write $(\omega_t)$ it is a shorthand for this.

Comment: Note that I did not specify the underlying state space $\Omega$ as I am looking for a possibly general answer. The notation you used was simply ambiguous until you made the assumptions explicit.

Comment: I further tried to verify the claim by writing
\begin{align}
f_* P ( \{ \omega_t \in B \} ) &= f_*P (  \{ \omega \in \Omega : \omega_t \in B \}  ) = P ( \{ \omega \in \Omega : f ( \omega ) \in \{ \omega_t \in B \} \}) \\
&= P ( \{ \omega \in \Omega : \omega - x \in \{ \omega_t \in B \} \}) = P ( \{ \omega \in \Omega : \omega \in \{ \omega_t - x \in B \} \}) \\
&= P ( \{ \omega \in \Omega : \omega_t - x \in B \}) = P ( \omega_t - x \in B )
\end{align} 
It seems that $f$ should rather map $\omega$ to $\omega + x$, or have I missed something?

Comment: Your previous comment does not make mathematical sense, and suggests to me some deeper confusion with the definitions. Rather than continue going in the circles in the comments here, I suggest you to review the precise definitions of stochastic processes. One source that covers this well (albeit in a terse writing style) is Olav Kallenberg's textbook "Foundations of modern probability", first four pages of chapter 2 (pages 22 through 25 in the edition I am looking at).

Comment: Could you kindly clarify what exactly makes you think that the comment does not make mathematical sense? Without excluding the possibility that there may be something wrong in the comment, it could also be the case that what I wrote is different from what you think I wrote.

Comment: You assumed that the sample space $\Omega$ is given by the functions from $T$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I tried to work with this assumption and followed the convention/notation on page 4 of this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=tbZPLquJjSoC&pg=PA4&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), right after Example 1.7. In the comment above, one could essentially replace $\omega_t$ ($t$ fixed) by $X_t ( \omega )$